# Windows offline domain join

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-domain

Apparently administrators can join the machine to the domain without a reboot according to this article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/offline-domain-join-djoin-step-by-step%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

I am sure there are downside of joining a domain without a reboot otherwise Microsoft would be using this method of joining the machines to the domain. Does anyone know about any downside of using this method to join machines to the domain?

Comment: Just by quickly reading that article, it seems like twice the work. 

This method requires two steps; 1) Create the object account on the DC, and 2) Inject the account data into the workstation. 

Joining a domain while online only requires the Administrator to take one step (connect to the domain) then reboot.

Comment: In fact, in some cases a reboot is also required when using the `djoin` command.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use online join because,
I have found that if you offline join and then don't reboot DNS resolution doesn't always work, group policy doesn't always take effect and also if you plan on doing anything with WinRM it probably won't work. I know this because of Nano Server something I dread to have to setup, for this very reason. Offline domain join is cool yes but in reality it still requires more work and a reboot if you want the computer in question to truly work with the domain.